# RxJava: Asserts not working

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java

I'm having some issues in a Unit Test that I'm coding with Robolectric. The thing is that I'm testing a UseCase, this UseCase uses an `rx.Observable` to do the asynchronous task, internally It also calls another `rx.Observable` which sorts a very large collection. I've injected the Schedulers in the UseCase, I tried using `Schedulers.immediate()`, `new TestSceduler()`, `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. Nothing seems to work. This is the execution flow:

```
...
@Test
public void testCacheConsistency() {
    AppComponent appComponent = getAppComponents(new EventList1MockRepository());
    injectFields(appComponent);

    //First we are going to request a list of events without using the cache
    getEventsInteractor.execute(new GetEvents.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onEventsFetched(List<Event> eventList) {
            assertTrue(false); //This asserts should throw an exception
            assertEquals(42343, eventList.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCachedEventsFetched(List<Event> eventList) {
            assertFalse("This method shouldn't be called", true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorFetchingEvents(String error) {
            assertFalse("This method shouldn't be called", true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorFetchingCachedEvents(String message) {
            assertFalse("This method shouldn't be called", true);
        }
    }, false);
    ...
}
...
```

First the test is called. Insde the GetEventsInteractor#execute method I'm doing this:

```
...
mRepository.getEvents(new BaseApiResponse<List<ApiEventResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            callback.onErrorFetchingEvents(error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(List<ApiEventResponse> apiResponse) {

            mapEventResponse(apiResponse)
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Event>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Event> items) {
                    mScheduleDbCache.setSchedules(mGetUserSipid.get(), items);
                    mScheduleMemoryCache.setSchedules(mGetUserSipid.get(),items);

                    callback.onEventsFetched(items);
                    onCompleted();
                }
            });
        }
        ...
}
...
```

I've to sort a pretty large list. The method mapEventResponses takes care of sorting that list inside an rx.Observable.

```
private Observable<List<Event>> mapEventResponse(final List<ApiEventResponse> apiResponse) {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Event>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super List<Event>> subscriber) {
            List<Event> items = new ArrayList<>();
            if (apiResponse != null) {
                for (ApiEventResponse obj : apiResponse) {
                    if (obj == null) continue;
                    items.add(EventMapper.transform(obj));
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Event>() {
                public int compare(Event ev1, Event ev2) {
                    return ev1.getmStartTs().compareToIgnoreCase(ev2.getmStartTs());
                }
            });

            subscriber.onNext(items);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(mBackgroundScheduler).observeOn(mMainScheduler);
}
```

This is the method, I checed that mBacgroundSceduler and mMainScheduler are properly injected.

Every step in this test case is executed perfectly, the problem is that when I reach the assets here:

```
assertTrue(false); //This asserts should throw an exception
assertEquals(42343, eventList.size());
```

Nothing happends, I tried with several combinations of schedulers, none worked. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong. The test 
ends up running successfully but It should obviously crash on those asserts.

Comment: seems like your test method returns before callback gets executed

Comment: You might have an error during your task and looks like you're not propagating errors to a callback. I also see that you're mocking repository, might be it doesn't do anything with task

Answer (score 0):

As @Eugen Martynov pointed out the issue is that the `rx.Observable` that I'm returning when calling the `mapEventResponse()` method is catching the `AssertException` and there it dies. One workaround that I found was creating an `ExceptionSubscriber` class:

```
public abstract class ExceptionSubscriber<T> extends rx.Subscriber<T> {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T t) {

    }
}
```

then the `AssertException` generated by the line `assertTrue(false);` It's propagated and handled properly.

For example:

```
    mRepository.getEvents(new BaseApiResponse<List<ApiEventResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            callback.onErrorFetchingEvents(error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(List<ApiEventResponse> apiResponse) {

            mapEventResponse(apiResponse).subscribe(new ExceptionSubscriber<List<Event>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Event> items) {
                    mScheduleDbCache.setSchedules(mGetUserSipid.get(), items);
                    mScheduleMemoryCache.setSchedules(mGetUserSipid.get(),items);

                    callback.onEventsFetched(items);
                    onCompleted();
                }
            });
        }
        ...
```

I'm open to any better solution.